# implementation on write-first single-port ram

Tags: verilog

Following shows a single-port RAM in write-first mode.

```
module raminfr (clk, we, en, addr, di, do);
        input        clk;
        input        we;
        input        en;
        input  [4:0] addr;
        input  [3:0] di;
        output [3:0] do;
        reg    [3:0] RAM [31:0];
        reg    [4:0] read_addr;
        always @(posedge clk)
        begin
           if (en) begin
              if (we) 
             RAM[addr] <= di;
                  read_addr <= addr;
           end
        end
           assign do = RAM[read_addr];
    endmodule
```

Here, how can we assure that output `do` is changed after `RAM[addr] <= di;` is executed?

If the logic does write-first mode, data has to be written first and then read has to happen. But, as we know, `RAM[addr] <= di;` and r`ead_addr <= addr;` are executed concurrently. However, it seems that we cannot guarantee that output `do` is changed after writing.

Why this code works?

Following are my exepctation:

**assumption: addr[10] = 5, addr[20] = 15;**

**previous addr: 10, current addr:10, en: 1, we: 0** => `do` = 5

**previous addr: 10, current addr:20, en: 1, we: 1, di: 12** => 
`do` will be changed because of RAM[read_addr] will be changed as 15. But, how can we assure that `do` will be 12 instead of 15 (write-first mode)?

Also, is the reg `read_addr` necessary? If it is, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here, how can we assure that output do is changed after RAM[addr] <= di; is executed?

Because  `assign do = RAM[read_addr];` will be executed when any of its signals change. Thus it will be called when either read_addr changes or if RAM changes. 
This makes that the `do` output follows both the address but also reflect any writes which happen.

The reg `read_addr` makes sure that the data of the last read stays on the output if `addr` changes. That is needed because `addr` must be ignored if there is no enable and if there is no clock.

The whole code builds a memory with a certain behavior. It may just not be the behavior you where expecting.

---

I hope the code formatting is not the original one. It is very sloppy. Also nowadays you should use modern port definitions:

```
module raminfr (
   input clk, // Memory synchronous clock
   input we,  // Write enable
   input en,  // Enable for both read and write
   ....
```

Adding the comment makes clear what each signal does. Thus it tells the user that the `en` is required for read and write. Otherwise she/he has to go working through the code to find out.

Final remark: just because you find some code which works don't assume it is the best there is.

Comment: Thks! If assign do = RAM[read_addr]; is fired whenever read_addr and RAM[read_addr]; is changed, the output do could show two results. First of all, if read_addr is changed, then do = RAM[read_addr]; can trigger data written in RAM[read_addr]  before writing happen. And, right after writing is done, then written data will be triggered to output do. Isn't it?

Comment: Signal changes will always 'ripple' trough a design. But that is all done in delta times. (In real life in gate delay times) In simulation with a synchronous design all the signals will be stable far before the next clock edge.